Frequency response of 5 transistor OTA

I need to calculate the open loop zeros and poles for this system.
What I tried is at some node between Gm2 and Gm1 block there will be one pole and value of effective capacitor is the capacitor which are Co1 and other got by miller approximated capacitance of Cc and 2nd pole will be at Vout node.
Will R(effective) at Vout node will be affected by Gm2 block? If yes, how can I solve that? If possible, please provide an expression for pole at node Vout.

Why not open the loop at the input of Gm1? Normally, the input resistance of an OTA is pretty high.

yes that loop will be open for sure , but u have doubt whether the conductance other than go2 will affect the pole at vout !!
and it will be very help if you can share the expression too!!

I think for pole/zero distribution it is the best way to find the corresponding transfer function. In this context, it is important to know if the OTAs may be considered as ideal (or not).

@RohitRajput - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, public & legal, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/video/etc name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (More rules in [tour] & [help].)
